# CATransform3D making my UITextView disappear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, catransform3d

So I have a UITextView that's supposed to be visually sitting on the bottom edge of the screen and then stretching up and back "into" the screen, "Star Wars" opening crawl-style.

After much googling etc, I feel like I have what looks like the right code for the job... but instead of setting up the perspective view I was looking for, this is just making the UITextView totally disappear!

The text view is set up in a storyboard with springs/struts (no autolayout) such that it's pinned at the top and bottom of the main view, about 20px in from each side, and the springs are active in both directions. Its outlet is hooked up to self.infoTextView. It shows up as I'd expect if I don't apply any transformations to it.

But when i fire off the code below in viewDidLoad, the text view just disappears completely. I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't seem to figure out what t is.

```
CGRect frame = self.infoTextView.layer.frame;
self.infoTextView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5f, 1.0f);
self.infoTextView.layer.frame = frame;

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 500;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 1.57, 0, 1, 0);
self.infoTextView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you'll need to modify in your code:

1. The rotation axis. You're rotating it around the Y axis. To get the
   effect you're after you will need to change the rotate transform to
   turn around the X axis.
2. To get "Star Wars opening crawl-style" effect you'll need to set a negative angle or a negative perspective.

Also, you would probably want to set a more "strong" perspective to achieve a more dramatic effect.

Here's an example based on your transform code:

```
CGFloat angle = -45;
CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / 200;
rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, angle / 180.0 * M_PI, 1, 0, 0);
self.infoTextView.layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Now I have another issue related to scrolling, but that's for another question...